# Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I get the below error message while I switch between my ember applications: 
version: 2.4.2
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit ember-cli.com for more info.
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
Could not serve on http://localhost:4200. It is either in use or you do not have permission.

Here are the packages that I have setup on my machine:
npm --version
2.14.20
bower --version
1.7.7
ember --version 
2.4.2
node: 4.4.0
os: linux x64

Answer (score 4):

Ember-cli (starting from release 0.1.3) requires watchman or some other service (e.g. NodeWatcher) for file watching.

You can find this info in the ember-cli release 0.1.3 changelog:
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.3

Although I believe you could use your Ember app without watchman, could you confirm that you already have watchman installed?

If not, here's what works fine for me in Ubuntu 64bit:

```
// installing watchman from source
git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
cd watchman
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

if you still have problems after installing try also resetting your watchman configuration:

```
watchman watch-del-all
watchman watch-del /home/myproject  // your project folder goes here...
watchman watch-project /home/myproject // your project folder goes
```

full installation instructions regarding watchman can also be found here
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html

Comment: `Ember-cli (starting from release 0.1.3) requires watchman or some other service (e.g. NodeWatcher) for file watching.` It does not require it, this is an issue with mac osx hitting the limit with node watcher, using node watcher on non osx systems is perfectly fine

Comment: Agreeing with @PatsyIssa on this. Still, it's left to point out that using watchman gives you the benefit of being able to configure your live reload server better, e.g. adding further directories to be ignored when watching the project for file changes.