# emberjs install on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ember.js

Any on help me..

I want to install emberjs on my ubuntu system..

I just follow emberjs official [site](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/getting-started/quick-start/#toc_install-ember) and install ebmerjs..

When i check ember versition..i have a 'watchman' error..

I use this command line

```
ember -v
```

And i have error look like this...

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
ember-cli: 2.9.1
node: 6.2.2
os: linux ia32
```

I tried to solve this error and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36194758/could-not-start-watchman-falling-back-to-nodewatcher-for-file-system-events) link,but i have another error

This is my stpes:

```
    // installing watchman from source
    git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
    cd watchman
    ./autogen.sh
    ./configure
    make
    sudo make install
```

When i put `make` command

I have error look like

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/karthick/watchman'
cd python && /usr/bin/python ./setup.py clean build_py -c -d . build_ext -i
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running clean
removing 'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7' (and everything under it)
error removing build/temp.linux-i686-2.7: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/pywatchman'
error removing build/temp.linux-i686-2.7: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build/temp.linux-i686-2.7'
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pywatchman.bser' extension
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pywatchman/bser.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/pywatchman/bser.o
pywatchman/bser.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:4139: recipe for target 'py-build' failed
make[1]: *** [py-build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/karthick/watchman'
Makefile:899: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any one Help me :( :(

When i create `ember new app_name` i got this error :(

```
Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events.
Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/karthick/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/karthick/.config/configstore/bower-github.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:634:18)
    at FSMonitor._measure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:66:21)
    at Object.openSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:82:30)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:502:33)
    at FSMonitor._measure (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:66:21)
    at Object.readFileSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:82:30)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:35:26)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/configstore/index.js:28:44)
    at readCachedConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a part of my script that helps me set up Ember on my ubuntu machines:

```
# ruby
sudo apt-get install ruby-full

# brew for linux
cd ~
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

# Add to your .bashrc or .zshrc
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"

sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper

# watchman
brew update
brew install watchman
```

I can provide full script, but I also install npm and java and other stuff, not necessarily related to EmberJS only.

Comment: ok thanks @pavol...i will try once it work..let you know.. :)

Comment: Oh, I think this might be related to incorrect python version, look:

`fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Make sure correct python version is installed. I am having Python 2.7.11+. Run `python -V` to find out your python version.

Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/34668690/1854744